# Using Expect in Bash to set the inital "postgres" user password?

Tags: bash, password, postgresql

Following the tutorial here: http://www.unixmen.com/install-postgresql-9-4-phppgadmin-ubuntu-14-10/

I am scripting the installation of PostgreSQL in bash but having a problem when it comes to setting the initial user password.

Following the tutorial for this part we have:

```
# Login to postgresql prompt:
sudo -u postgres psql postgres

# .. and set postgres password with following command:
postgres=# \password postgres 
Enter new password: 
Enter it again: 
postgres=# \q
```

Which is great but I want to set this password from the Bash script and one way that this type of task could generally with would using Expect:

```
# Build the command into a variable so that we can run it later
PSQL_QUERY=$(expect -c "

set timeout 10
spawn -u postgres psql postgres -c '\\\password postgres'

expect \"Enter new password:\"
send \"password\r\"

expect \"Enter it again:\"
send \"password\r\"

expect eof
");
# Run the command with automated entry
echo "$PSQL_QUERY";
```

But when I try to run the script I get output as follows:

```
root@node:/home/user# ./test.sh 
send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"send "password\r""
spawn sudo -u postgres psql postgres -c '\password postgres'
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres'"
```

Which I don't really understand both because I am new to PostgreSQL and because when I run the following:

```
root@node:/home/user# sudo -u postgres psql postgres -c '\password postgres'
Enter new password: <password>
Enter it again: <password>
```

It works. Could someone please help me with the understanding of where I am going wrong with this and how I could get it right so that I can set the new "postgres" user password from within a bash script. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33144870/1030675

Comment: @choroba Yes thanks, i did this on purpose as im unsure of where i would get support, it relates to both sites and i will delete the one that gets the least attention. I assume that you have no answer?

Comment: Great example of the way the tools we know affect the way we develop. Using expect here is just completely wrong (no offense intended of course).

Comment: @don.joey I humbly accept your constructive criticism, I am rather novice. That being said, you are correct as thinking logically there would be a way with psql to do this directly. I am still perplexed as to why the error occurred with expect but I guess that I will shrug this off for a better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Much easier:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD '{password}';"
```

[Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html) on `psql` (PostgreSQL interactive terminal).

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you so much :-)

Comment: @IndigoIdentity: Don't thank Rinzwind!  **;-)** If this answer did help, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey ☑ *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!

Comment: @Fabby Hehe, thank you for the beginners tutorial. I did give him an up vote but was unable to select it as the answer just yet ;)

Comment: It would be useful to note that http://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name suggested that "You can supply the initial password when running initdb using the --pwfile= option" which works too but I do not necessarily want to take this approach as it adds more to the logic then what I want to accomplish directly.